# Projective representations of $\mathrm{SL}_n(K)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero, and let $\overline{K}$ be an algebraic closure of $K$.  Is it true that the irreducible, projective, rational representations
$$
\SL_n(K) \rightarrow \GL_m(\overline{K})
$$
are just restriction to $\SL_n(K)$ of the Weyl modules plus field automorphisms?  References and comments are most appreciative.  Thanks!

Note: Rational representation == given by rational map of algebraic varieties.

Comment: I guess it should follow from highest weight theory that all homomorphisms of algebraic groups $SL_n\to PGL_m$ are defined over $\mathbb Q$. (Since both groups are split.) Hence there is no Galois action to consider, only those Homs of algebraic groups.